# Python creating new Dictionary from older one between indexes

Tags: python, list, dictionary, text-parsing

I am new to python but I was wondering how I can approach this. I want to copy all the lines between the indexes 4 and 20, 20 and 25 and put that as the value in a new dictionary.

```
def cutting(my_sequence):    
    code={}
    text=dict(my_sequence) #converts my sequence which has line numbers as key and line as value
    list=[4,20,25] #holds line numbers I want to cut between
    #now what?Here is where I have to find out how to make a new dict with all the lines in between as value
    return code
```

For example,

If the text takes the form of something like

```
{0:'hello guys this is the start\n',
 1:'this is the first line\n',
 2:'this is the second line\n'}
```

and I want something like this for my output dictionary code:

```
{0:'hello guys this is the start\n this is the first line\n',
 1:'this is the second line\n'}
```

Comment: What is `my_sequence` to start with? A list of tuples? Dictionaries don't have order, so the word "between" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: I also don't really understand your example. Why does `"this is the first line\n"` lose its trailing newline in your example output? Why do we combine `0-1` and not `2`?

Comment: needs better examples of inputs and expected outputs. could be a case for `OrderedDict` or using `enumerate` on the dictionary.

Comment: my_sequence looks something like [(0,'hello guys this is the start\n'),(1,'this is the first line\n')] and so on... So I guess a list of tuples yes.

Comment: @Sudocode is the list of tuples ordered by definition? Could you ever have `[..., (3, "some text"), (1, "other text"), ... ]` ?

Comment: @Adam Smith Yeah it is ordered I would like to keep it that way. What I did was convert a text file to a list of tuples where each line has a line # and is associated with line of text just those " in your example are single quotes like '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like dictionaries are the wrong choice here. Let's use lists instead. Since we're ignoring original line numbers, we can infer them from their position in the list.

```
def cutting(my_sequence: "list of tuples of form: (int, str)"): -> list
    flat_lst = [v for _, v in my_sequence]
```

This builds a list of JUST the text. Now let's build a list of ranges to work with

```
    lines_to_join = [5, 20, 25]
    ranges = [range(lines_to_join[i],
                    lines_to_join[i+1]) for i in range(len(lines_to_join)-1)]
    # ranges is now [range(5, 20), range(20, 25)]
```

There are prettier ways to do that (see the `pairwise` function in the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)), but this will work for this small application

Next, let's use `"\n".join` to glue together the lines you want.

```
    result = ["\n".join([flat_lst[idx] for idx in r]) for r in ranges]
    # you might want to strip the natural newlines out of the values, so
    # # result = ["\n".join([flat_lst[idx].strip() for idx in r]) ...]
    # I'll leave that for you
    return result
```

Note that this will throw `IndexError` if any of your indexes in `ranges` fall outside of `flat_lst`.

All together we should have something like:

```
def cutting(my_sequence: "list of tuples of form: (int, str)"): -> list
    flat_lst = [v for _, v in my_sequence]lines_to_join = [5, 20, 25]
    ranges = [range(lines_to_join[i],
                    lines_to_join[i+1]) for i in range(len(lines_to_join)-1)]
    # ranges is now [range(5, 20), range(20, 25)]

    result = ["\n".join([flat_lst[idx] for idx in r]) for r in ranges]
    return result
```

Comment: thanks this works ... my only thing is lets say each element is now a SQL statement. Any ideas on how to test if the syntax is correct for this query? ~~ maybe im asking too much haha :)

Comment: @Sudocode Sounds like a different question to ask! Also sounds like you're going about this ENTIRELY wrong and this is only an answer to your XY question. I would write a new question starting from the beginning -- "How do I build SQL queries from a text file"

Comment: haha ok well thanks for answering this one though it was informative, maybe I am doing it wrong so ill post a new one.